# Legal Recourse American Airlines Threw Me Off Flight

Tags: travel, air-travel

I was recently thrown off an American Airlines Flight under the pretext that my suitcase had contained a laptop (information I had ill-advisedly volunteered to the lady at the desk right before boarding), leaving my pregnant wife and 2.5 year old to fly all by themselves.

They sent me down to passenger check-in again to get my suitcase under the pretext that having a laptop in checked luggage is a hazard. When I got down there, they sent down the wrong suitcases, and left the suitcase that contained the laptop in the belly of the airplane, and took off anyway (shocker!).

I was blue with anger. Either the pretext was complete bull (which of course it was, since the TSA says that it's completely OK to have laptops in checked luggage: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/laptops), or they are grossly incompletent, putting my pregnant wife and kid, and the rest of the airplane in danger.

Is there legal recourse here?

Comment: Is there a reason you are incapable of speaking to a legal professional about this?

Comment: The TSA isn't the only federal agency regulating what you can check.  See what the FAA has to say (but beware: it is confusing and seems to be self-contradictory): https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/portable-electronic-devices-with-batteries

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim, unwilling is a better choice of words than incapable.

Answer (score 3):

AA "requests" that you remove batteries from checked laptops and put them in carry-on luggage. You must, per their [contract of carriage](https://www.aa.com/i18n/customer-service/support/conditions-of-carriage.jsp), "comply with airline safety rules", and they say that they can deny you boarding if you do not comply, which includes "Are uncooperative, abusive, harassing, or show the potential to be while on board". You might then hope to sue them because you didn't violate any safety policy of theirs but they denied you your seat, but there's nothing in the contract that states "The following is a complete list of policies". You should discuss this in more detail with your lawyer, but on the face of it there is no legal recourse, except of course a refund.

Comment: Why do we selectively answer some requests for legal advice and close others?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite It depends on whether the post gets 5 closes or an answer first.